# Why to use Statement, if PreparedStatement improves performance

Tags: java, jdbc

As per explanation given for [`PreparedStatement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) in the [JDBC docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html), I see that it improves the performance compared to [`Statement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html).

So why we still use Statement and it is not deprecated? Can you please explain.

Comment: Please provide some explanation before giving negative votes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PreparedStatement allocates some resources on DB server side while simple Statement does not. It may cause some difference in performance when executing a single SQL

Comment: The resource allocation depends on the database and driver. For some JDBC drivers/databases the allocation for a statement and prepared statement are the same.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the docs, a `PreparedStatement` usually out-performs a normal `Statement` when executing a query several times:

> An object that represents a precompiled SQL statement.
>
> A SQL statement is precompiled and stored in a `PreparedStatement` object. This object can then be used to efficiently execute this statement multiple times.

This is what the `PreparedStatement` is used for. But not everything is about performance: When the query has no variables in it with everything hardcoded, and is to be executed once, the `Statement` is just *simpler* to use. It doesn't quite make sense in creating a prepared statement with all its potential benefits if you intend to run a hardcoded query only once. In fact, in this case it won't differ much if you use a `PreparedStatement` because the executed method is the same, e.g. `Statement#executeQuery()` because `PrepareStatement` is a subclass of `Statement`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. But is it just about simplicity in using Statement? Because if PreparedStatement is used the same code looks similar right, Please let me know if  I am missing something here.

Comment: @user3181365 You can use it for a query with no parameters. But you probably won't notice a difference in terms of performance, and even in simplicity as it would be exactly similar to the `Statement` for this case. It's just that you're using an "enhanced" `Statement` subtype for a simple task.